# WorkItemStore.Query("YourQuery") Getting Error when fetching data from TFS in .Net c#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, tfs

I'm getting this problem when I'm fetching data from VSTF server using following code. 
Can you help me how can I extend its Collection Size or something else to achieve more records.

```
Uri tfsUri = new Uri(uri);
 TfsTeamProjectCollection tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(tfsUri, tfsCredential);
WorkItemStore workItemStore = new WorkItemStore(tfs);
var query = workItemStore.Query(projectquery);
```

**I'm getting error In last row of this code. Please follow the following error given below:**

> Processing Team Project "[MyProject]"  An error occurred while
>   processing Team Project "[MyProject]": VS402337: The number of work
>   items returned exceeds the size limit of 50000. Change the query to
>   return fewer items. 
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.VerbatimMessageException:
>   VS402337: The number of work items returned exceeds the size limit of
>   50000. Change the query to return fewer items. ---> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: VS402337: The number of
>   work items returned exceeds the size limit of 50000. Change the query
>   to return fewer items.  at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Proxy.RetryHandler.HandleSoapException(SoapException
>   se)  at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Proxy.WorkItemServer.QueryWorkitemCount(String
>   requestId, XmlElement psQuery, Boolean useMaster, Int32& count,
>   DateTime& asOfDate, MetadataTableHaveEntry[] metadataHave, String&
>   dbStamp, IMetadataRowSets& metadata)  at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore.QueryWorkItemCount(String
>   requestid, XmlElement queryXml, DateTime& asof)  --- End of inner
>   exception stack trace ---  at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore.QueryWorkItemCount(String
>   requestid, XmlElement queryXml, DateTime& asof)  at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.Query.RunCountQuery(String
>   requestId)  at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore.QueryCount(String
>   wiql, IDictionary context)  at
>   TeamProjectManager.Modules.WorkItemConfiguration.WorkItemTypes.WorkItemTypesViewModel.<>c__DisplayClass82_0.b__0(Object
>   sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) in
>   C:\Users\jelled\Desktop\Code\TfsTeamProjectManager\Repo\TeamProjectManager.Modules.WorkItemConfiguration\WorkItemTypes\WorkItemTypesViewModel.cs:line
>   169  Retrieved 22 work item types

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways to fix that:

- Add the Query conditions to return fewer items just as the error 
  message mentioned.

  eg:

  `SELECT * FROM WorkItems WHERE [System.TeamProject] = @project AND [System.State] = ‘Active' AND [System.AssignedTo] = ‘joselugo'`
- Split into groups to return them separately. There is a sample for retrieving list of all work item types for your reference: (See [Github](https://github.com/jelledruyts/TfsTeamProjectManager/issues/21) for details.)

  `// There is a VSO limit of a query returning 20,000 results. Split into groups of 10,000 items maximum.
  var results = new List<WorkItemReference>();
  var counter = 10000;
  var moreResults = true;
  while (moreResults)
  {
      List<WorkItemReference> currentResults = this.WitClient.QueryByWiqlAsync(new Wiql
      {
          Query = $"SELECT System.ID FROM WorkItems WHERE System.TeamProject = '{Project}' AND {customQuery} AND System.ID >= {counter - 10000} AND System.ID < {counter}"}).Result.WorkItems.ToList();`

  ```
  if (currentResults.Count == 0)
  {
      // Verify there are no more items
      try
      {
          results.AddRange(this.WitClient.QueryByWiqlAsync(new Wiql
          {
              Query = $"SELECT System.ID FROM WorkItems WHERE System.TeamProject = '{Project}' AND {customQuery} AND System.ID >= {counter}"
          }).Result.WorkItems.ToList());

          moreResults = false;
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
          if (e.ToString().Contains("VS402337"))
          {
              // There are still more results, so increment and try again.
          }
          else
          {
              throw;
          }
      }
  }
  else
  {
      results.AddRange(currentResults);
  }

  counter += 10000;
  ```

  }

Comment: @vicky Have you resolved your issue by above workaround? any update for this?