# VSTS - VS402337: The number of work items returned exceeds the size limit of 20000. Change the query to return fewer items

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

In VSTS, I get this when there are more than 20k work items returned by a wiql query. I wanted to know if there is a parameter to limit the number of work items returned(even though the actual query may return 20000+ work items)?

> Caused by: com.microsoft.tfs.core.ws.runtime.exceptions.SOAPFault:
> VS402337: The number of work items returned exceeds the size limit of
> 20000. Change the query to return fewer items.

Comment: Not get your latest information, is Matt's workaround helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Comment: Is there any parameter similar to top while using the TFS SDK? Where we use query() method of WorkItemClient class?

Answer (score 1):

In this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45407279/11508192), Andy gave two methods to fix this issue, you can refer to it.

1.Add the Query conditions to return fewer items just as the error message mentioned.

For example: `SELECT * FROM WorkItems WHERE [System.TeamProject] = @project AND [System.State] = ‘Active' AND [System.AssignedTo] = ‘joselugo'`

2.Split into groups to return them separately.

```
// There is a VSO limit of a query returning 20,000 results. Split into groups of 10,000 items maximum.
var results = new List<WorkItemReference>();
var counter = 10000;
var moreResults = true;
while (moreResults)
{
    List<WorkItemReference> currentResults = this.WitClient.QueryByWiqlAsync(new Wiql
    {
        Query = $"SELECT System.ID FROM WorkItems WHERE System.TeamProject = '{Project}' AND {customQuery} AND System.ID >= {counter - 10000} AND System.ID < {counter}"}).Result.WorkItems.ToList();

if (currentResults.Count == 0)
{
    // Verify there are no more items
    try
    {
        results.AddRange(this.WitClient.QueryByWiqlAsync(new Wiql
        {
            Query = $"SELECT System.ID FROM WorkItems WHERE System.TeamProject = '{Project}' AND {customQuery} AND System.ID >= {counter}"
        }).Result.WorkItems.ToList());

        moreResults = false;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        if (e.ToString().Contains("VS402337"))
        {
            // There are still more results, so increment and try again.
        }
        else
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
else
{
    results.AddRange(currentResults);
}

counter += 10000;
}
```

This workaround is for .net tfs sdk, I think you are using java tfs sdk, you can refer to the above code logic to modify.

Comment: But it looks like the system ID for a work item is unique across different projects. And if I am searching for work items in a particular project, and the first ID in that project is greater than our counter, this would fail, right?

Comment: It looks like this from the code sample, you can modify the code according to the actual situation.

Answer (score 0):

When using the [Wiql API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/wiql/query%20by%20wiql?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0), if you specify a value for `$top` it will limit it to the maximum results to return.

Comment: Is there any parameter similar to top while using the TFS SDK? Where we use query() method of WorkItemClient class?

Comment: While using the Wiql REST API as you mentioned, is there still a limit of 20,000 work items or the $top value can be anything we want, for example 100,000?